# Using htaccess to serve sitemap from a remote server

Tags: .htaccess

is it possible to display my sitemap from a remote server like its residing on a main server

say
  mydomain.com/sitemaps/filename.xml

will get its content from

remoteserver.com/sitemapts/mydomain-sitemap-filename.xml

and how do i do it in htaccess.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it requires that [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) has been enabled on the server. If you don't control the server yourself, this could be a problem.

Assuming it is available though, and `mod_rewrite` is also available to you, you could something like this in a `.htaccess` file in your site root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sitemaps/(.*)\.xml$ http://www.example.com/sitemaps/%{HTTP_HOST}-sitemap-$1.xml [P]
```

Comment: Many thanks.. i'll try this one.. yes most likely mod_rewrite is enanlbed on the server.